# In envoy script console command raise error

Tags: laravel-envoy

With laravel 5.8  envoy command I deploy my changes on server and need to run some console command and I my script
I got error

```
Could not open input file: artisan
```

on the second console command

In my script :

```
@task( 'update_symlinks' )
ln -nfs {{ $release_number_dir }} {{ $current_dir }};

@foreach($writableDirs as $file)
    chmod -R 777 {{ $release_number_dir }}/{{ $file }}

    chown -R {{ $server_login_user }}:www-data {{ $release_number_dir }}/{{ $file }}

@endforeach

cd {{ $release_number_dir }}

php artisan envoy:write-app-version app_version  // THAT WORKS OK

@endtask



@task('clean_old_releases')

php artisan envoy:delete-old-versions  Hostels2Deployed  // BUT THAT raise error

@endtask

@macro('Hostels2Deploy',['on'=>'dev'])
    ...
    update_symlinks
    clean_old_releases
@endmacro
```

envoy:delete-old-versions defined in app/Console/Commands/envoyDeleteoldVersions.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class envoyDeleteoldVersions extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'envoy:delete-old-versions {directory_to_clear}';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()     
    {       // php artisan envoy:delete-old-versions  "/_wwwroot/lar/Hostels2/storage/app/public/hostels"

        $arguments = $this->arguments();
        if ( !empty($arguments['directory_to_clear']) ) {
            $directory_name = $arguments['directory_to_clear'];
        }
        $directoriesList = File::directories($directory_name);

        $sortedDirectories = collect($directoriesList)
            ->sortBy(function ($dir) {
                return filemtime( $dir );
            })
        echo '<pre>+++ 222 $sortedDirectories::'.print_r($sortedDirectories,true).'</pre>';
        die("-1 XXZ");
    }
}
```

Why error and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a decision that I had to select app root directory at first  :

@task('clean_old_releases')
    cd {{ $release_number_dir }}

```
php artisan envoy:delete-old-versions  Hostels2Deployed
```